# How to measure quality of coordinate conversion?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I'm using PROJ.4 in my work and now I want to know how it convert coordinate well, especially longitude/latitude <-> UTM.

I can compare the result from proj command with values from some websites which provide coordinate conversion, but I don't think I can convince my clients or my supervisors with such unofficial data.

Is there any official or authorized reference to test coordinate conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proj.4 itself has a large test suite.

The US military-based agency, National Geo-information Agency (NGA) has a ["Gold Data"](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/Conversion_Software/index.html) set that they use to certify their GEOTRANS software. As UTM was originally defined by the US military, that should be considered official.

The oil & gas industry released a test suite, [Geospatial Integrity of Geoscience Software](https://www.iogp.org/bookstore/product/geospatial-integrity-of-geoscience-software-part-1-gigs-guidelines/) that also covers Universal Transverse Mercator. Those tests are based on entries from the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org)

Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.